# Codeinigter PHP + Twitter Login

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth, twitter

I am trying to implement a Twitter login on my Codeigniter page.

First I have downloaded the Twitter Libraries from [Twitter Simon Emms](http://www.simonemms.com/2012/02/22/twitter-for-codeigniter/)

Then I have placed the files correctly and edited **config/twitter.php**

```
'_tokens' => array(
    'consumer_key' => 'mykey',
    'consumer_secret' => 'mykeymykey',
```

etc...

Then when calling the **twitter_test controller** and trying to login
I just get redirected to http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you registered your application? : https://dev.twitter.com/apps

Comment: Yes! I have registered my application. I have tried with another OLD API Lib and it is working. Still for me its not satisfying since its old.

Comment: It is working partly, only. So I don´t recommend using this anymore. Throwing error in line 203 in the Library. Seems to be too old. CLOSED

Comment: hi can you plz help i need the same

Comment: Twitter Simon Emms this library is not available now

Answer (score 1):

I got caught on this one myself many times. This is actually in the Twitter API setup, you need to specify the callback URL. It doesn’t matter what it is as you will specify the callback URL in the code. I would suggest putting the root page to your site in (same as what would be generated by site_url())